# Differences between Java and Delphi .NET

Tags: java, delphi, delphi.net

I was forced to learn the Delphi .NET language even though it is kinda dead now. But I only have some experience with Java, so I was wondering what is the difference between them actually?
I tried searching it on the Internet but Delphi .NET (not normal Delphi) results were kinda rare. Therefore I am looking for help here.
For instance, are both languages object oriented or interpreted? A more detailed explanation of their differences (on important aspects) would be helpful.

Comment: Different syntax but in other aspect very similar. Both compiled to an intermediate language and then JIT compiled to native code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for the reply. Would you be so kind to explain their difference to me? For example, is both language support operator overloading or dynamic array kind of thing?

Comment: There are very few significant differences. If you know both languages as you say in the question then you already know the answers. If you have to use delphi.net then it doesn't really matter what java is. This isn't a real question as described in the [faq].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an old Delphi software developer and a currently Java and .NET developer  (C# and Visual Basic), I would recommend you to make the little effort to join to the C# or VB languages if you are planning to jump to the .NET platform.

They are mainly used, and the amount of information and samples on the web related with them makes ok the time spend on learning. Also the work opportunities for C# and VB will be bigger than in Delphi .NET (and I ensure you that I loved Delphi).

As I read, it seems that your change is not voluntary, but If you have the opportunity, I would recommend you to tell your boss about migrate their system to one of this.
.NET is of course object oriented, and uses some kind of JIT (just in time compiler, as Java does). C# and VB are really good languages, perhaps C# is more similar to Java because of its syntax, but they are almost the same.

Remember that no matter what language in the .NET platform you use. It is all translated to the same pseudo-code so the performance will be the same (with the exception of C++), and it is only a matter of what’s the most comfortable language for you.

Hope this helps.

Tom

Comment: *"I would recommend you to tell your boss about migrate their system to one of this."* - I wouldn't.  His boss will probably ask him what the value of migrating is ... and honestly, there is little value if the existing system works and is maintainable.  (And I'd say exactly the same thing about migrating to any other language / platform.)

Comment: +1 I think it's a pretty good answer

Comment: @StephenC migrating it to C# will help, because from what I know(could be wrong) there aren't many Delphi .Net developers out there, so it would be wise to have many developers that could take the project at any given time

Comment: Migrate from one language to another in the .NET platform is not the same as migrate from different platforms. I didn’t migrate projects from Delphi .NET, but I do from VB to C#, and yes, it takes time, but is not hard (I think there were “automatic” tools to help you with the work).

Of course, it must be his boss who must take the decision, and it depends on many things we don’t know, but the main advantage for his boss with the migration will be to have a lot of people ready to start with his project tomorrow, and not having to wait for people to learn Delphi .NET each time...

Comment: ...he needs people for the project, or taking the risk of Microsoft stop supporting Delphi .NET in the future. I think those are powerfull arguments.

Perhaps is the moment to migrate, perhaps not. It was only a way of see the problem, and of course without knowing all the things involved on it.
PS: The problem would be for “user1238193” if his boss decides to migrate, and then decides to hire another worker that already knows about .NET, and left  “user1238193” without job. This would be a good reason for not to tell! ;)

Comment: @tomasofen "and left “user1238193” without job. This would be a good reason for not to tell!" I am strongly against such practice, I have yet to find myself without job whenever I've given similar advices, on the contrary, the "boss" sees(or at least should see) value in the fact that you're thinking long term, usually a problem should be solved once if possible, bosses know that they are not always right and most of them would love to be contradicted(with strong arguments) if it helps solving the problem better.

Comment: Actually I have no choice, you see, I am still a student and was forced to learn this languge this semester. Therefore I was trying to look for their similarities and difference to make my learning process easier.